# Where did the Homekit Accessory Simulator go in Xcode 6 beta 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, homekit

In Xcode 6 Beta 5 and previous betas, I could open a HomeKit Accessory Simulator by right-clicking on the icon in the dock and choosing Open Developer Tool > HomeKit Accessory Simulator. In Xcode 6 beta 6, this seems to be no longer the case:

[image]

How can I launch the accessory simulator now?

Comment: printerSimulator also appears to be gone...

Comment: @LiGe It's also been moved to the Hardware IO tools package - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25416770/1849664).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you read [release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_6_gl2i5q/xcode_6__beta_6_release_notes.pdf)

> HomeKit Accessory Simulator
>
> • HomeKit Accessory Simulator is now
> included in a separate product called Hardware IO Tools  for Xcode,
> available on developer.apple.com/downloads. (17738621)

Comment: It's now part of the "Additional Tools for Xcode". Currently this link https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_9.3/Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_9.3.dmg

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is in Xcode go to Xcode->Open Developer Tools->More Developer tools.
It will redirect you to Apple developer portal. Choose to download Hardware IO Tools for Xcode
The HK simulator is one of the installed application

Answer (score 3):

Copy HomeKit Accessory Simulator.app to your Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/ directory and it will appear in the Xcode Open Developer Tool menu

Answer (score 2):

Recently (in 2016) Apple has moved the HomeKit Accessory Simulator to Additional Tools for XCode Package: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=additional%20tools

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was moved to the **"Hardware IO Tools for Xcode"** package, available from [this page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action):

> #### Hardware IO Tools for Xcode - Late August 2014
>
> This package includes additional hardware i/o tools formerly bundled in the Xcode installer. These tools include: Apple Bluetooth Guidelines Validation, Bluetooth Explorer, **HomeKit Accessory Simulator**, IO Registry Explorer, Network Link Conditioner.prefpane, PacketLogger and Printer Simulator. These graphics tools support running on OS X 10.10 and OS X 10.9.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

It comes as an app after you open the .dmg:

[image]

Looks like you just move it to /Applications, and it works fine.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to download HomeKit Accessory Simulator? I tried moving the HomeKit Accessory Simulator in /Applications but still xcode cannot find it in "Open Developer Tools". I am using xcode 6.0.1