# Unable to download HomeKit accessory simulator for Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7.3, homekit

I'm trying to download HomeKit Accessory Simulator but unable to download it.

From Xcode I'm trying it to download from two sides:

1) From the Capabilities section:

[image]

2) From the Xcode's Open developer Tools:

[image]

By clicking on them I landed on the page:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode

Which gives me some random response in some Json format :

```
     {"responseId":"d730b398-8ae9-43da-8d08-1335372fd1ca","resultCode":1003,"resultString":"request.uri.notfound","userString":"Invalid request, Service mapping to the requested URL is not available. ","creationTimestamp":"2016-07-22T11:53:06Z","userLocale":"en_US","requestUrl":"https://developer.apple.com:443/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode","httpCode":200,"suppressed":[]}
```

Any help and suggestion will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: It seems that Apple website server has some issue. May be it will work later.

Comment: No, I'm trying this link since last 10 day and this issue is always there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I found what I really want, here we go: **Hardware IO Tools for Xcode 7.3.dmg**

http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Hardware_IO_Tools_for_Xcode_7.3/Hardware_IO_Tools_for_Xcode_7.3.dmg

This package includes additional hardware i/o tools formerly bundled in the Xcode installer. These tools include: Apple Bluetooth Guidelines Validation, Bluetooth Explorer, HomeKit Accessory Simulator, IO Registry Explorer, Network Link Conditioner.prefpane, PacketLogger and Printer Simulator. These graphics tools support running on OS X 10.11.

Answer (score 1):

May be Apple link is broken.

Go to below link:

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

and Download:  ***Hardware IO Tools for Xcode***

*This package includes additional hardware i/o tools formerly bundled in the Xcode installer. These tools include: Apple Bluetooth Guidelines Validation, Bluetooth Explorer, HomeKit Accessory Simulator, IO Registry Explorer, Network Link Conditioner.prefpane, PacketLogger and Printer Simulator. These graphics tools support running on OS X 10.10 and OS X 10.9.*

open the `.dmg` and you will see it as app inside it:

[image]

then move it to `/Applications` and you are good to go.

Also check answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25416770/5575752 by Undo♦ for more detail.

Comment: I guess Its broken since last few days, no idea why Apple don't able to fix it.